# What does "curl" mean?

Tags: javascript, facebook, curl

I'm developing Facebook JavaScript apps on a daily basis, but keep stumbling into some code snippets I don't understand, on the Facebook Documentation, and other websites I visit.

I searched Google for CURL, and found some descriptions about it. I can't figure out how Facebook wants me to use it.

```
curl -F "title=Example Title" -F "description=Description" \
-F "start_time=1329417443" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/milestones?access_token=_"
```

It's nonsens for me. Can you help me understand in what context I can use it for Facebook , and maybe in general, and guide me in the right direction where to find more on the subject?

Comment: BTW, 'curl' stand for "client URL", see more in this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788997/what-does-the-c-in-curl-stand-for

Answer (score 14, accepted):

curl is a command line utility that lets you send an HTTP request. It can be very useful for developing with web service APIs. I believe it comes pre-installed with most linux distros but you would need to download and install it for Windows. (It probably comes with Cygwin but can be installed on its own as well.)

I would suggest making sure it's directory is added to your PATH environmental variables. Again, probably not a problem in linux but you will need to do this manually in windows.

Answer (score 7):

[`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) is a command to fetch requests. The `-F` (`--form`) argument is used to specify form POST parameters.

Citation from `man curl`:

```
   -F/--form <name=content>
          (HTTP) This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a  user
          has  pressed  the  submit button. This causes curl to POST data
          using the Content-Type  multipart/form-data  according  to  RFC
          2388.  This enables uploading of binary files etc. To force the
          'content' part to be a file, prefix the file  name  with  an  @
          sign. To just get the content part from a file, prefix the file
          name with the symbol <. The difference between @ and < is  then
          that  @ makes a file get attached in the post as a file upload,
          while the < makes a text field and just get  the  contents  for
          that text field from a file.
```

Comment: PS. I though that it's obvious that the last argument to `curl` is the location to where the form is submitted. Adding this note, just in case.

Answer (score 2):

`curl` is a way of [fetching items](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_curl.htm). The `-F` is one of many parameters...

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Also:

Have you seen http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

and it could be useful for something like:

http://chaolam.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/implementing-facebook-real-time-updates-api-with-curl-examples/

Answer (score 0):

of course FB docs use curl to show a common basic way to perform the request ... it depends on what platform language  libraries are you using the actual way to perform the graph http request

...so that if you are Facebook JavaScript developer you have to use XMLHttpRequest (or i suppose facebook js lib calls)