# What does the 'c' in cURL stand for?

Tags: curl

I know that cURL is a command line utility that lets you send an HTTP request, but what does that 'c' stand for?

Comment: I too was wondering this. People who downvoted this clearly have no curiosity.

Comment: Understanding acronyms helps them stick in your memory... especially the mad ones (why not the recursive version: "Curl URL Request Library").

Comment: Chinese Version (繁體版本, CHT, zh-rTW)： 我知道 cURL 是一個命令列工具，能夠讓你傳送 HTTP 請求，但是 'c' 是代表什麽 (表示什麽) (c 是什麽字的縮寫)？

Answer (score 66, accepted):

From their website:

> cURL is the name of the project. The name is a play on 'Client for
>   URLs', originally with URL spelled in uppercase to make it obvious it
>   deals with URLs. The fact it can also be pronounced 'see URL' also
>   helped, it works as an abbreviation for "Client URL Request Library"
>   or why not the recursive version: "Curl URL Request Library".

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#What_is_cURL

Comment: Chinese Version (繁體版本, CHT, zh-rTW)：
cURL 是專案的名稱。 這名稱是關於 'URLs的客戶端'，原本是使用大寫拼法的 URL 來表明它就是處理 URLs。 cURL 也可以發音為 'see URL'(同 c URL) 的事實，對取名為 cURL 也有幫助。它可以作為 "Client URL Request Library (客戶端URL請求函式庫)" 的縮寫，或者為何不是遞迴版本: "Curl URL Request Library (Curl URL 請求函式庫)" (遞迴原因：Curl URL Request Library 的 Curl 又是什麽)。


（若有翻譯錯誤，請在協助更正，謝謝。）

Comment: If a server blocks access whit curl, try whit -A "Client URL Request Library". :-)